# Tengo un problema con la api de google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Cordial saludo,

Estoy presentando un problema con la api de google maps que me esta arrojando este problema

> InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with
> finite coordinates: in property lat: not a number,

Este problema tendrá algo que ver con un cambio de certificado ssl que se le hizo a la pagina web, pues cuando reviso la url donde llamo la api key del mapa esta si esta https://

Agrego el codigo
/* Aca cuando le de click a un boton abre el modal donde se ingresa la direccion y la ubica en el mapa y le pasa las coordenadas al metodo que inicializa el mapa */

$(".NewDir").click(function() {

```
$("#myModalCarrito").modal('hide'); 

$('body').removeClass('modal-open');

$('.modal-backdrop').remove(); 

$('#myModalMapa').modal('show');

initializeGMap1(4.71099, -74.0721);
```

});

/* Inicializa el mapa */

function initializeGMap1(lat, lng, zoom) {

```
new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    zoomControl: true,
    center: { lat, lng },
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

document.getElementById('address').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
});
```

}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {

```
var latitude;
var longitude;

var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {

    if (status === 'OK') {
        setMapOnAll(null);
        markers = [];
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        positionF = results[0].geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: resultsMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        markers.push(marker);

        latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

        longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        localStorage.setItem("latitude", latitude)

        localStorage.setItem("longitude", longitude)

    } else {

        console.log("error api");

        $('#errorDir').css("display", "block");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#errorDir').css("display", "none");
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Hola, David. Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Podrías, por favor, modificar tu respuesta y añadir un poco más de información como por ejemplo parte del código para poder ayudarte de una forma más concreta. Por el ValueError, podría ser el tipo de datos con el que está tratando (string) no sea el correcto, pero con más información podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: Tienes que transformar a float los valores que recibe la función, por defecto los toma como string.

Comment: Yo a las coordenadas les hago un parseFloat y sigue el mismo error